# How do I merge transactions in Banktivity?

Tags: banktivity

I imported my current account and my credit card and correctly categorized all transactions. Banktivity failed to recognize the transactions from my current account to my credit card so now I have two:

[image]

How do I merge them as they are the same?

Comment: I've never used Banktivity, but can't you just delete one of the duplicate transactions?

Comment: @BenMiller I would be afraid of it appearing the next time I import data from my bank.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a "product or service recommendation" question. OP clearly describes a specific problem and asks how to solve it; there is no obvious product recommendation aspect there. The product being asked about does appear to be relevant to personal finance, so it seems on topic. We have many similar questions about how to do various things with GnuCash, which from the looks of it is a similar piece of software, so there's certainly precedent.

Comment: I've reopened as the close reason was indeed wrong. I'm not entirely sure it's on-topic though: there's been some [debate on meta](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-questions-on-the-technical-usage-of-a-financial-management-tool-be-on-top) - no clear consensus but in practice other technical support questions about tools have survived.

Comment: Definitely on-topic in my book.  Thanks for re-opening @GaneshSittampalam.

Comment: I understand the re-open. The reason I clicked was not quite on track. OP has created the tag for banktivity, asked 3 questions, and answered one himself. The others have no replies. This is a product I never heard of. That aside, I expressed my feelings in Meta, that such questions should be asked of the seller of this software or at their site. If this were a brand new product, all three questions would be shut as spam. I see no difference here.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expected such controversy. I ask about all sort of products on Stack Overflow and it's never an issue. I was surprised there wasn't a Banktivity tag as it's one of the main solutions for personal finance for the Mac (not many, you have Quicken for Mac and that's about it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The people from Banktivity answered my question: you drag one transaction on top of the other and they get merged.

Comment: This doesn't work in Banktivity 7

Comment: I'm using Banktivity 7 (version 7.1.4) and merging transactions as described above *does* work for me.

Comment: This does not appear to work in Banktivity 8